# results depends of other results in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array named action of 1000 observations; from `0` to `99` means `100` observations were taken randomly then I want to count the value of action based on a matrix of 2 column called R which depends on the value of action.
I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-930470b1de32> in <module>()
     19 print(R)
     20 for i in range(100,999,1):
---> 21     if R[i-1,0]>R[i-1,1]:
     22         action[i]=1
     23     else:
IndexError: index 99 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 99
```

The code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
import random

action=np.zeros((1000))
def reward(action,i,n):
    R=np.zeros((n,2))
    for i in range (i,n,1):
        if action[i]==1:
            R[i,0]= 1+action[i]/2
        else:
            R[i,1]=1+action[i]/2
    return R
random.seed(771)
for i in range (0,99,1):
        action[i]=random.randint(1,2)
print(action[0:99])
R=reward(action,0,99)
print(R)       
for i in range(100,999,1):
    if R[i-1,0]>R[i-1,1]:
        action[i]=1
    else:
        action[i]=2
    R=reward(action,100,999)
```

Comment: full traceback please..

Comment: IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-930470b1de32> in <module>()
     19 print(R)
     20 for i in range(100,999,1):
---> 21     if R[i-1,0]>R[i-1,1]:
     22         action[i]=1
     23     else:

Comment: Do you mind update your post with Traceback nicely formatted. It will be human friendly then.

Comment: Look at the shape of `R` using `print(R.shape)`. Then look at your second for loop which starts at 100. The shape of `R` is (99,2) which is giving you the error

Comment: I did @jlandercy

Comment: Why do you initialize action with 1000 values, but then it only sets up 100 of those values in the for loop?

Comment: R.shape is (99,2)  @JahKnows because i started 100 actions randomly then i want to fill action from 100 to 999 with values resulting from R

Comment: excluding or including 999? (same for 99) See answer...

Comment: @RawiaSammout, check the answer, the error is caused due to the way you index your matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R=reward(action,0,99)` creates a list of 99 elements:

```
>>> len(R)
99
```

then when you run

```
for i in range(100,999,1):
    if R[i-1,0]>R[i-1,1]:
```

which will generate indexes starting from 99 but last index of R is 98 (goes from 0 to 98 thus lenth of 99).

Try: `for i in range(99,1000,1):`

Answer (score 0):

The end index for a range in Python is not included. For example the first 100 values would be given as [0, 100). Thus the 100th index is not included, but the zeroth is included. This is written as `action[0:100]`.

This should work for you.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
import random

def reward(action,i,n):
    R=np.zeros((n,2))
    for i in range (i,n,1):
        if action[i]==1:
            R[i,0]= 1+action[i]/2
        else:
            R[i,1]=1+action[i]/2
    return R

random.seed(771)

action=np.zeros((1000))
for i in range (0,100,1):
        action[i]=random.randint(1,2)
print(action[0:100])
R=reward(action,0,100)
print(R)

for i in range(100,999,1):
    if R[i-1,0]>R[i-1,1]:
        action[i]=1
    else:
        action[i]=2
    R=reward(action,100,999)
```

Comment: Why edit my post to make it incorrect. The range written `action[0:100]` is defined as the indices [0, 100). Not (0,100). These are not the same. The type of parenthesis is important.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Go in detail about what you are trying to do and we can write this code out and make it work?

Comment: What does the definition `reward` do? What do you want it's input to be and its output.

Comment: my code is below i want to apply reinfrocement learning model to my data principle is explained in detailed below in the main function

Comment: @RawiaSammout, I mean explain to me the actions and rewards. What are the rules by which to set these values.

Comment: I started by taken 100 actions randomly 0 or 1 then i have to calculate the count of number of times N the action 0 and 1 was taken for 4 states then after determining N ,i have to calculate the RHO that stores the cumulative sum of previous rewards when action was 0 or 1 finally i gonna calculate the average reward R [i,0], R[i,1]for action 0 and action 1

Comment: then i restart the calculation of action from 100 to 2265 based on the results of previous reward means if R[i-1,0]>R[i-1,1], action is 0 else 1

Comment: @RawiaSammout, what is RHO? How is it calculated?

Comment: @RawiaSammout, Ok given a list of 100 random values either 0 or 1, then what are the 4 states? How are they determined?

Comment: RHO has 8 column for the 4 states because the action in each state can be 0 or 1,RHO[i,k] = RHO[i,k]+r[i] represents the cumulative sum of previous rewards and is calculated based on the action in each state if the action is 0 and state is 1 so RHO[1,0]= RHO[1,0]+r[i]

Answer (score 0):

I applied the same principle on my datset but it didn't work no error but no results

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime as dt
from numpy import random
import pandas as pd
import random
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#import excel file
df1 = pd.read_excel('new.xlsx')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1) 
df1.head(8)
df1['WMRT'][0]
#discretization of walmart
wal = np.zeros(df1.shape[0])
for i in range(1,df1.shape[0],1):
    if (df1['WMRT'][i] > df1['WMRT'][i-1] ):
        wal[i]=1
    else:
         wal[i]=-1
df1['wal']=wal
print(df1['wal'])
#Discretization Dow Jones
djd = np.zeros(df1.shape[0])
for i in range(1,df1.shape[0],1):
    if (df1['DJ'][i] > df1['DJ'][i-1]  ):
        djd[i]=1
    else:
         djd[i]=-1
df1['DDJ']=djd
print(df1['DDJ'])
#codification of the state based on the Dow Jonesindex and walmart values
state = np.zeros(df1.shape[0])
for i in range (1,df1.shape[0],1):
    if (df1['DDJ'][i]== -1 and df1['wal'][i]== -1):
        state[i]=1
    elif(df1['DDJ'][i]== 1 and df1['wal'][i]== -1):
        state[i]=2
    elif(df1['DDJ'][i]== -1 and df1['wal'][i]== 1):
         state[i]=3
    else:
        state[i]=4
df1['state']=state
print(df1['state'])
#training phase (i=4616)
#generate the same sample each time
random.seed(771)
#intialize randomly the actions for 100 observations
def number_update(action,p0,n):
    N = np.zeros((n,8))
    for i in range(p0,n,1):
        N[i,:]=N[i-1,:]
        k=int(2*(state[i]-1)+action[i])
        N[i,k]=N[i,k]+1
    return N
def Rhoo(action,p0,n):
    RHO = np.zeros((n, 8))
    r = np.zeros((n))
    for i in range(p0,n,1):
        RHO[i,:]=RHO[i-1,:]
        k = int(2*(state[i]-1)+action[i])
        if k in [0,2,4,6]:
            r[i]=df1['WMRT'][i]/df1['WMRT'][i-1]-1
        else:
            r[i]=df1['DJ'][i]/df1['DJ'][i-1]-1   
        RHO[i,k] = RHO[i,k]+r[i]
    return RHO
#Average reward for each action 0 and 1
def reward(N,RHO,p0,n):
    R = np.zeros((n, 2))
    for i in range (p0,n,1):
    #j : even number
    #k : odd number
        k = 0
        for j in range(0,7,2):
            if N[i,j] != 0 :
                  R[i,0] += RHO[i,j]/N[i,j]
            else : 
                 R[i,0] = 0
            k = j+1
            if N[i,k] != 0 :
                R[i,1] += RHO[i,k]/N[i,k]
            else : 
                R[i,1] = 0
    #print(R)
    return R
def reward_max(action,p0,n):
    r = np.zeros((n))
    for i in range(p0,n,1):
        k = int(2*(state[i]-1)+action[i])
        if k in [0,2,4,6]:
            r[i]=df1['WMRT'][i]/df1['WMRT'][i-1]-1
        else:
            r[i]=df1['DJ'][i]/df1['DJ'][i-1]-1   
    return r
#determine the action
def main():

    action=np.zeros((df1.shape[0]))
    train, test = train_test_split(df1, test_size=0.3)
    #Training the model
    #generate the same sample each time
    random.seed(771)
    # take 100 action randomly
    for i in range(0,100,1):
        action[i]=random.randint(0,1)
    print(action)
    print(type(action))
    #N is the number of time the action 1 or 0 was taken from a state i
    print("N")
    N =number_update(action,1,100)
    print(N)
    #RHO represents the cumulative sum of the previous rewards obtained every time the action 0 or 1
    print("RHO")
    RHO = Rhoo(action,1,100)
    print(RHO)
    # represents the average reward for every action 0 or 1
    print("R")
    R = reward(N,RHO,1,100)
    print(R)
    for i in range(100,2265,1):
        if(R[i-1,0]>R[i-1,1]):
            action[i]=1
        else:
            action[i]=0
        N = number_update(action,100,2265)
        RHO = Rhoo(action,100,2265)
        R = reward(N,RHO,100,2265)
    print(action[100:2265])
    print(R.shape)

main()
```